# Xcode6 blocks some static libs in static lib, but not others

Tags: ios, xcode6

Until xcode6, we had:

1. library target "appshared" builds a static lib and embeds multiple other static libs
2. Multiple apps embed static lib appshared, and automatically get the embedded static libs too

Now, with Xcode6, and a new 3rd party static lib (from MixPanel, who never quite seem to know what they're doing with packaging iOS binaries), score refuses to embed the new static lib, saying:

"can't locate file for -l[library name]
 file: -l[library name] is not an object file (not allowed in a library)"

What's wrong with this new library, and ... any ideas what I have to ask the provider to fix in their build setup? (they don't share the source, sadly)

Answer (score 0):

## facepalm

It's a bug in Xcode 6 - nothing to do with the particular library.

Xcode **no longer supports spaces in folder names**, even though this has been a core requirement from Apple Corp for all Mac software for > 15 years; apparently, they don't test this for Xcode any more, and someone wrote some very bad code (probably: used the wrong (20 years old) method calls for manipulating file paths; if they'd used the correct ones, space-handling is automatic and implemented by the OS, IME!)

---

Solution: when you drag/drop libraries into Xcode 6, if there is a space in the folder name, Xcode will corrupt the build settings, and add a library-import-path for each word in the folder name.

You have to edit your Build Settings, find your library search paths, and you'll see it has lots of stupid values. Delete those, put the real path, and surround it in double-quotes.

All will then work fine.